# Couchdb how to get the timestamp of the last modified database?

Tags: couchdb

Does anyone know how to get the last timestamp that a specific database was modified?
The API _changes does not provide that information. Thank you.

**UPDATE**
How to retrieve the last date /time that the database had anew document inserted or a modified one.

Comment: "last modified database" could mean 1) adding or removing user access 2) modifying a document 3) any configuration change 4) etc etc.  Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB does not record the time that each change occurred, so if you need this functionality you need to a add a timestamp into the document e.g.

```js
{
  "_id": "myid",
  "name": "Bob",
  "email": "bob@aol.com",
  "timestamp": 1657614546263
}
```

Then a MapReduce view will allow you to query documents by `timestamp`:

```js
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.timestamp)
}
```

To get a the latest change you would query the resultant view with `?descending=true&limit=1` to get the most recently modified document:

```
GET /mydb/_design/myview/_view/myview?descending=true&limit=1&include_docs=true`
```

Alternatively, you can use a document id that has a timestamp encoded within it. See [this blog post](https://blog.cloudant.com/2018/08/24/Time-sortable-document-ids.html) which shows how documents with time-sortable ids allow easy querying of the latest documents to be added.